# Expand a range columns into a single column

Tags: oracle, select

I'm thinking this is an easy query but I don't know how to start. I have a database table called `Booklet` with columns `id`, `controlNoFrom` and `controlNoTo`. Sample data looked like this:

```
id       | controlNoFrom | controlNoTo
---------+---------------+-------------
20150105 |             1 |         100
20150106 |           101 |         150
20150107 |           151 |         225 
---------+---------------+-------------
```

What I want is a query that can present the data like this:

```
id       | controlNo
---------+-----------
20150105 |         1 
20150105 |         2
20150105 |         3
...      |       ...
20150105 |        99 
20150105 |       100
20150106 |       101
20150106 |       102
...      |       ...
20150106 |       149
20150106 |       150
20150107 |       151
20150107 |       152
...      |       ...
20150107 |       224
20150107 |       225
---------+-----------
```

It's easy if it is the other way around, but I don't know what kind of SQL to be used in this scenario. What would you call this approach and what would the SQL statement in OracleDB look like?

Comment: You can use `CONNECT BY` or a recursive CTE. Or a tally table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some kind of row generation technique, for example:

```
select rownum - 1 as q from dual connect by level <= (select max(controlnoto - controlnofrom) + 1 from booklet)
```

This generates as many rows as the largest range requires, with data `0, 1, 2, ...`, starting with `0`, so no correction needed, when we add these values to `controlnofrom`. Now simply join this to your original table and limit the number of rows by `controlnoto - controlnofrom`, finally add the row number to `controlnofrom`:

```
with booklet as
(
  select '20150105' as id, 1 as controlnofrom, 100 as controlnoto from dual union all
  select '20150106', 101, 150 from dual union all
  select '20150107', 151, 225 from dual
)
select
  b.id as id, b.controlnofrom + r.q as controlno
from
  booklet b
  join (select rownum - 1 as q from dual connect by level <= (select max(controlnoto - controlnofrom) + 1 from booklet)) r on (r.q <= b.controlnoto - b.controlnofrom )
order by
  id, controlno
;
```